# Easiest way to clean user-entered city names with Pandas / AWS

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
index cycle-time city state
0        5       albany ny
1        3       alyany ny
2        7       albny ny
3        2       ALBANY ny
4        5       Albany ny
```

What is the fastest way (in terms of effort required) using Python Libraries or AWS Services to detect all similar spelling and edit them
to equal the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a dictionary of allowed names. Then you need to normalize all the names to lowercase. Finally I would use the python library [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) for each row in the name compared to the dictionary name. If it is matched by fuzzywuzzy at over N% (probably 90%) change it to the expected value.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
name_in_question = "albinany"
for allowed in allowed_names: # you would probably want to narrow the allowed names list down based on other data or the first charater
    percent_match_to_allowed = fuzz.ratio(allowed, name_in_question)
    if percent_match_to_allowed > 90:
         name_in_question = allowed
```

You could make this an inline function and apply it to pandas in a lambda function. I would also try to reduce the size of allowed_names based on the input as much as possible. Good Luck normalizing these names - it is a hard task but doable - just hard to make performant.